# Replacing content between two div tags - PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to replace content between two div tags using str_replace but I'm unsure how.

The content will be

```
<div class="profile-details">
<div class="username">Paradigm</div>
<div class="dob">01/01/2015</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is replace the content between the `<div class="profile-details">content </div>` tags. The content is variable depending on the user profile.

Comment: To make this easier on you, if you're doing manipulation of HTML use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I assume you have this HTML in a string? You have to use regex

Comment: What sort of regex? the information would change such as the username so I cant hardcode this into str_replace otherwise I would have done a string replace of the entire content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a HTML string.
This would be my approach

```
echo preg_replace('/<div class="username">.+?</div>/im', '<div class="username">Special Username<\/div>', $string) ;
```

Comment: Would this replace the entire content between the profile-details tags?

Comment: If instead of class="username", you use class="profile-details", then yes, it would the entire content of that div.

Comment: @Paradigm good! select my answer as the best answer and upvote it please then ;)